# Uniform continuity of $\sin(x\sin x )$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I want to prove or disprove that $f(x)=\sin(x\sin x)$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$ is uniformly continuous.

We know that $g(x)=x\sin x$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$. But what about $f$? I am not getting any hint. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can guarantee that this function is not uniformly continuous, because it's derivative oscillates faster as $x \to \infty$, hence the maximum and minimum which are $-1$ and $1$ are achieved faster. But I'm not able to make this rigorous.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг There are uniformly continuous functions whose derivatives oscillate wildly and unboundedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider $f(2\pi n + \pi/n) - f(2\pi n).$

Comment: I got it. Thanks!